# Resizing of text size when text changes to fit in the control

Tags: c#, winforms, font-size

I am trying to write a method that would resize the text font size so that the text is properly and completely visible in control.

The method which i tried for this is a follows,

```
public static void FitControlFont(Control control)
        {
            if (control.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            Font currentFont = control.Font;
            Graphics graphics = control.CreateGraphics();
            SizeF newSize = graphics.MeasureString(control.Text, control.Font);
            graphics.Dispose();

            float factorX = control.Width / newSize.Width;
            float factorY = control.Height / newSize.Height;
            float factor = factorX > factorY ? factorY : factorX;
            if (control.InvokeRequired)
            {
                control.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { control.Font = new Font(currentFont.Name, currentFont.SizeInPoints * factor); }));
            }
            else
            {
                control.Font = new Font(currentFont.Name, currentFont.SizeInPoints * factor);
            }
        }
```

The above method works very well but, 
My question though here is that how can i use text as multiline?
I get the text in single line(because of which the text appears very small).

I am using label and button as my controls used in the forms whose text font need to be re sized when text changes.

Comment: Do you want to resize vertically if your text doesn't fit?

Comment: I dont want to resize control actually, only want to resize text so that it uses complete control space.

Comment: Graphics.MeasureString has several overloads, you'll need to use the one that takes an additional SizeF (the maximum size) and possibly a  StringFormat that matches the one you use in your DrawString call.  Do favor TextRenderer instead of Graphics.

Comment: @NomeshGajare have you tried passing in the **actual multi-line Text** into `MeasureString`? This code looks OK to me as long as the `MeasureString` works OK.

Answer (score 0):

This method will do the job. It may look a bit more complex as it has to work in two ways: either increase the text size if the initial text is too small or decrease it if it's too big initially.

If the text is too small, it will be increased until it cannot fit vertically (as horizontally it will break into lines itself).

If the text is too big, it will be decreased until it can fit into the control's rectangle.

The control has to be multiline.

You can control the size change by changing the value of `step` variable.

```
public static void FitControlFont(Control control)
{
    if (control.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    Graphics graphics = control.CreateGraphics();
    Font newFont = (Font)control.Font.Clone();
    bool sizeFound = false; // to test if we already found the right size
    bool initiallyToSmall = false; // is the initial text to small (we will increase the font size) or too big (decrease the font size)
    float step = 1F; // increase/decrease step
    SizeF newSize = graphics.MeasureString(control.Text, newFont, new SizeF(control.Width, control.Height));
    if (newSize.Width <= control.Width && newSize.Height <= control.Height)
        initiallyToSmall = true;

    do
    {
        newSize = graphics.MeasureString(control.Text, newFont, new SizeF(control.Width, control.Height * 2));
        if (initiallyToSmall)
        {
            if (newSize.Height > control.Height)
            {
                newFont = new Font(control.Font.Name, newFont.SizeInPoints - step); // get previous size
                sizeFound = true;
            }
            else
                newFont = new Font(control.Font.Name, newFont.SizeInPoints + step);
        }
        else
        {
            if (newSize.Width <= control.Width && newSize.Height <= control.Height)
                sizeFound = true;
            else
                newFont = new Font(control.Font.Name, newFont.SizeInPoints - step);
        }

    } while (!sizeFound && newFont.SizeInPoints > 1 && newFont.SizeInPoints < 100);

    graphics.Dispose();

    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        control.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { control.Font = newFont; }));
    }
    else
    {
        control.Font = newFont;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. but when i suddenly minimise the view all the text on the controls is not complete(cut horizontally) and takes lots of time to become normal size again